# jboss-web.xml context path name is different from war file's name

Tags: jboss

The context-path name in jboss-web.xml is different from the application which we deploy in jboss-5.0 GA.

My application creates some files with in the applications sub-folders. but when it goes to create files it searches the application with the name which is mentioned is jboss-web.xml file.

I use exploded-war file as my application, which is like file. Inside this many folders are there.

```
<context-root>/Test</context-root>
```

but my application name is `Test-0.0.1`

---

Hi Actually /Test is my context-path name in jboss-web.xml

Comment: It's not clear what your question is

Comment: Actually i create some cache file inside my application. But when i go to write cache files it searches for application name with Test but my applications name is Test-0.0.1. Is there any method using which i can get this Test-0.0.1. I am trying to use strContextPath() vut it returns Test.

Answer (score 0):

context-root is used to tell application server as which webapp should a request be delegated to based on the URL. Now from my understanding you ant to access the resources inside your application as like http(s):/:/Test/YouResourceName.
To do something like that I will suggest to keep the context-root as Test(not starting with '/'). You need to specify web-uri as the child element of  tag where you have specified context-root. So it should look something like

Test-0.0.1.war
            Test